# $f:X\to Y$ continuous and open, prove: if $D\subseteq Y$ is dense $\implies f^{-1}[D]$ is dense

Tags: general-topology

I know $D\subseteq Y$ is dense $\implies \overline{D}=Y$ or $D\cap U\neq\emptyset$ $\forall$ $U$ open. Also if $f$ is continous then $f^{-1}[U]$ is open. I suppose that $f^{-1}[D]\cap f^{-1}[U]\neq\emptyset$ may be false. I don't know how an open map takes part on the proof.

Answer (score 1):

Let $V$ be  a non-empty open set in $X$. We have to show that $V \cap f^{-1}(D)$ is not empty. Now, since $f$ is an open map,  $U=f(V)$ is a non-empty open set in $Y$. Since $D$ is dense there is some point $y \in D \cap U$. Since $y \in f(V)$ we can write $y=f(x)$ with $x \in V$. Now verify that $x \in V \cap f^{-1}(D)$ to finish the proof.

Comment: ok writing U as f(U) was the key, thanks!!!!

Comment: @Robert $U=f[V]$, not $U=f(U)$.

Comment: @Robert Note that the continuity of $f$ is not even needed or used.

Comment: i wanted to say f(V), a misprint, thanks

Comment: @HennoBrandsma   you need continuity of f  to say that $f^{-1}(D)$ is open, didn't you?

Comment: @Robert $f^{-1}(D)$ need not be open even if $f$ is continuous. The proof does not use the fact that $f^{-1}(D)$ is open.

Comment: @Robert **If** $D$ is open (which it is not in your problem) and **if** you want $f^{-1}[D]$ to be open (you ask for dense only) then you need continuity of $f$.

Comment: sorry, it was a confusion, i was thinking about  the open set needed for the definition of dense $f^{-1}\cap V\neq\emptyset$ not about $f^{-1}(D)$, but as you define V as open at the begining there is no mistake. Thanks!!!!!!!!!!!